# Using wget to download specific subfolders only downloads the robots.txt and the index.html files

Tags: bash, unix, download, wget

I am trying to download all the `.nc` files from here: https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/

The link includes a tree structures of varying subfolders, e.g.:
https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/1992/11/goes07/netcdf/ So, I have to instruct `wget` to recursively download data for all the years folders.

Also, at the second-last level (e.g. https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/1992/11/goes07/), I need to exclude the `csv` folder and keep only the `netcdf` folder.

By running the following line, however, I only get the `robots.txt` and the `index.html` files:

```
wget -r -l4 -np -nH -x "https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full" -A "*/*/*/netcdf/*"
```

Same if I run:

```
wget -r -np -nH -x --force-directories robots=off "https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: the following ones are not working either:

```
wget -nH -x --force-directories -e robots=off -r --include-directories="*/*/netcdf" https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/{1981..2012}/

wget -nH -x --force-directories -e robots=off -r -X "*/*/csv/" -I "*/*/netcdf/" https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/{1981..2012}/
```

Comment: Front-running a web portal with bots is tricky and can cause issues to the portal because it is not designed for automation. Better use their public API https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2 that is actually designed for this purpose.

Comment: The `/robots.txt` file, that you were able to download by the way, tells all robots to stay out of this website. `wget` respects this.

Comment: @LéaGris The dataset I am looking for is not in the list of the public API, from what I can see @ @PierreFrancois: the problem is that data is not downloaded (even specifying `robots=off`)

Comment: The option `robots=off` must follow the flag `-e`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pierre! It is downloading now, also keeping the directories tree, but for each subfolder it's still downloading only the `index.html` file

Answer (score 0):

```bash
wget -m -np -e robots=off "https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full"
```

Maybe you can use this method for downloading.